# Generating lean image from a large base image

Tags: docker

Is it possible to generate a docker image much smaller in size than the base image? 
The scenario is that I have limited options of base images to work with and they are large generic images.

e.g. If my base image size is 100 MB, can i create an image from this base image and still have it much smaller by removing unnecessary packages? 
I tried it and was able to remove the packages successfully during image build , but did not see a change in image size.

It sounds counter intuitive from what I know about Docker. But still wanted to check with the community and experts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason why you did not see a change in image size:

Docker depends on a layered filesystem. One interesting feature of layered filesystem is that lower layers are immutable to upper layers. When you remove some files, you are creating a new layer on top of the whole stack of layers. These files are just invisible in your new layer, but they **remain to exist in the lower layers**.

One way to achieve a lean image:

Use Docker's multi-stages build. Build your own image on a small base image, and use `COPY --from=large-image files files` instruction to copy necessary files from the large image.

---

Update: there is another (tricky) way to generate a smaller image from a large image.

It's possible to flatten a container.

Assuming you have built an image named `myimage`. Now run a container from it, and note the id of the container.

Run the following command to generate a new image:

```
docker export <id> | docker import - myimage-new
```

This `myimage-new` is smaller in size than the original image. But of course it does not contain any build history (which can be inpected by `docker history`) any more.

Comment: I agree. This is also what my understanding is. However, in my case, as I mentioned earlier, I don't have the option of using a lean base image , all the images are 95MB+.